# How to Bind a list to the layout which is expanded on click of the list item

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which there is an activity where I need to bind the listviews and onClick of that listview item I need to expand a layout below it and that layout should consist of a listview and two buttons I’m successful in Binding the list to the listview but I’m not getting how to bind the items to the inner listview. Can anyone help me out and Thanks in advance.

Here is the code for binding the list to the inner listview.

```
public class BindToRecurrenceList extends BaseAdapter{
Context context;
private ArrayList<String> list;
private Activity activity;
private LinearLayout expandable_rec_list;
private TextView tvRecurListContent;
private ListView itemList;
ImageButton imgAddItems,imgExportItems;
String Item;
public BindToRecurrenceList(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> list) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflate=activity.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflate.inflate(R.layout.list_rec_expandable, null);
        expandable_rec_list=(LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandable_rec_list);
        itemList=(ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_list_rec);
        imgAddItems=(ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add_item_rec);
        imgExportItems=(ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.export_items);
        convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(itemList, imgAddItems,imgExportItems, expandable_rec_list,expandable_rec_list.getVisibility()));
    }
    tvRecurListContent=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recurr_list);
    ImageView DelRecList=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.del_rec_list);

    tvRecurListContent.setText(list.get(position));
    ArrayList<String> labels=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        labels.add("item "+i);
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> qty=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        labels.add(i+".00");
    }
    ArrayList<String> qtyType=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        labels.add("Piece");
    }
    BindingRecurrenceListItems adapter=new BindingRecurrenceListItems(activity,labels,qty,qtyType);
    itemList.setAdapter(adapter);
    imgExportItems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            alert.setMessage(activity.getString(R.string.rec_list_items_export)+" \""+list.get(position)+" \""+activity.getString(R.string.rec_list_dialog));
            alert.setPositiveButton(activity.getString(R.string.proceed), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, PurchasesActivity.class));
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton(activity.getString(R.string.frag_btn_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            }).show();
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ExpandableListView for this purpose.

[this link](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/expandable-listview-inside-scrollview/#sthash.Wc6qFaBn.dpbs) may help.